# How do I use multiple classes in css module based on a const?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-css-modules

Currently my extraClassName const is never read and I would like the css module to follow what extraClassName is based on the if statements. Not sure how to go about doing this.

````
render() {
    const { isFinish, isStart } = this.props;
    const extraClassName = isFinish
      ? "node-finish"
      : isStart
      ? "node-start"
      : "";

    return <div className={`node ${styles.extraClassName}`}></div>;
  }```
````

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my question after poking around. The last case should be added in as styles.node as state does not matter while the const of extraClassName (which should now be renamed) should hold the css modules of the classes I want to edit. Thanks for all the replies and help I've gotten!

```
  render() {
    const { isFinish, isStart } = this.props;
    const extraClassName = isFinish
      ? styles.nodeFinish
      : isStart
      ? styles.nodeStart
      : "";

    return <div className={`${extraClassName} ${styles.node}`}></div>;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

extraClassName is just a variable in the local scope, it doesn't appear to be on a styles object.

So you should be able to just write:

```
return <div className={`node ${extraClassName}`}></div>;
```

and it should work.

If you're doing a lot of this conditional class rendering, there are some useful npm packages such as `classnames` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) or `clsx` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx), which make writing these conditional classes a little nicer.

**Example**

```
import clsx from 'clsx';

...

return <div className={clsx('node', {
  'node-finish': isFinish,
  'node-start': !isFinish &&isStart
})}></div>;
```

If you're wary of npm packages for such a small utility, it's also pretty quick and easy to write a similar utility library for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply! but I should elaborate: I would like my div to follow the css module styles based on what extraClassName is. following your code I realised that nothing is taking after my styles from my css modules.